# Disable Bluetooth device on Ubuntu

Tags: macintosh, bluetooth

I run Kubuntu Quantal on a Macbook 8-2 and want to disable the Bluetooth device.

Yeah, disable, not just hide or stop a deamon, but shut off the damn hardware.

I know it can be done on Lenovos using

`echo 0 > /sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/bluetooth_enable`

but for Macbooks? Someone briefly told me about `-bt 0` but couldn't really remember ... and that string is certainly hard to google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can blacklist the bluetooth kernel module:

```
echo bluetooth >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

This should disable the device from being initialized.

---

As far as `-bt 0`.  I was able to google it with *disable bluetooth "bt 0"*.  The first result suggests it was a flag passed to `hal` to disable bluetooth.  Unfortunately `hal` is depreciated so this method will no longer work.

Comment: Yap, with reference to hal I found `/usr/lib/hal/hal-system-smbios --bt 0`. Thanks. But udev should have a similar feature. I'll google that...